# Django: Way to Get List of All Running Commands?

Tags: python, django

If I run `htop`, I see a list of all running processes, and the commands that spawned them.

[image]

Is there a way to get the list of running commands from inside Django? I looked at the docs for the [OS module](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/pythons-os-module), but didn't yet spot a way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "running commands"? The views that are currently running?

Comment: On the far right of the window, it lists the name of the command, e.g. `python3 /my_directory/my_app/manage.py rssrun --settings=server.settings.prod_cnf`. I'd like to load this list within my Django app if possible.

Comment: Load what list? The list of currently running Django processes?

Comment: The same list displayed by `htop`. I've got a cron job that runs regularly. I want it to check this list to see if it's still running from a previous launch and if so, exit immediately. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of currently running processes you can use `ps`

```
result = subprocess.run(['ps aux | grep rssrun'], capture_output=True, shell=True)
print(result.stdout)
```